# Create folder if it does not exist in the Google Drive

Tags: java, google-drive-api

My Application works with Google Drive Java API.

I want to create folder in the root of the Google Drive only if it does not exist. I am using below code to creat folder.

```
  file = service.files().insert(body).execute();
```

How do i check the folder existance in the root folder. I have only the folder name 'Myapp', not the instance ID.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Files.List request = service.files().list().setQ(
       "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false");
FileList files = request.execute();
```

You could now go through all folders in "files" and check if any of the folders have the searched title.

Don't forget to loop through all pages with:

```
request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
```

**Edit:**

Maybe you could have a look at  [this site](https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters). You can add the title in your search criteria instead so you do not have to retrieve all the folders.

Comment: That will work, but I think a query of


"mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false and title='MyApp' and 'root' in parents "


will either return the folder he's looking for, or an empty list so no need to iterate through nextPageToken

Comment: @pinoyyid
Exactly. That is what I meant in the edit of my first answer.

Comment: Correction: as of today, to query for a file or directory name, the field is `name` and not `title` as suggested above.

Answer (score 3):

```
Files.List request=service().files().list().setQ(
                   "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false and name='"+folderName+"'");
        FileList files = request.execute();
```

Above line of code is used to get the list of all the files/folder with given name. If files are empty, it means files or the folder with given name doesn't exist and you can create a new folder with below mentioned line of code:

```
File fileMetadata = new File();
        fileMetadata.setName(folderName);
        fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

        File file = service().files().create(fileMetadata)
            .setFields("id")
            .execute();
```