# how to find out isFolderExist and isFileExist in Google Drive using Java?

Tags: java, google-drive-api, drive

I want to upload new file under a given path 
if path does not exist , i want to create that path by creating directories, and then upload that file, If path exist i just want to put my file on that path.

for. e.g.
'pandora' is name of my main folder on google drive
i want to do all the directory and file manipulations under it.

```
folderPath = /panodra/augusta/weber/

fileName = DEC
```

in following method i am trying to find out 'pandora' folder but it is returning empty item list.

```
private static boolean isFolderExist(String folderPath, String fileName) throws IOException {

            Files.List request = drive.files().list().setQ(
                "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false and title='pandora' ");
            FileList files = request.execute();
            List<File> fl1 = files.getItems();
            System.out.println(fl1);
            System.out.println(files);
            return false;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the Folder part, there is no clear way to get this if you check the Drive [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder). What can I give you is a related SO question that can do it but it uses the Google Drive Android API. So just check it and get the idea on how to do it.

- [Google Drive Android API - Check if folder exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713482/google-drive-android-api-check-if-folder-exists)
- [Create folder if it does not exist in the Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811705/create-folder-if-it-does-not-exist-in-the-google-drive)

For the Files part, you can check the [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) part of the Google Drive documentation to search the files. It uses the [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) method of the Drive API that accepts `q` parameter which is a search query combining one or more search clauses.

Here is a [sample code](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters#using_client_libraries) on the documentation that shows how to perform a search of image files.

```
String pageToken = null;
do {
FileList result = driveService.files().list()
.setQ("mimeType='image/jpeg'")
.setSpaces("drive")
.setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
.setPageToken(pageToken)
.execute();
for(File file: result.getFiles()) {
System.out.printf("Found file: %s (%s)\n",
file.getName(), file.getId());
}
pageToken = result.getNextPageToken();
} while (pageToken != null);
```